# Не работает простой сценарий на Python

Tags: python, syntax

**Не работает простой сценарий на Python.**

- Когда s = 8 выводится 012345.
- Когда s = 7 ничего не выводится.
- Когда s = 3 выводится 012345.
- Когда s = 1 ничего не выводится.

```
s = 1

if s == (8 or 7):
    print("012345")
elif s == (3 or 1):
    print("543210")

input()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кто вас такому научил?

```
if s == 8 or s == 7:
```

или

```
if s in (8, 7)
```